# How do I get the url stored in ":back"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, back

It's easy, and common, to redirect to :back in Rails.

However, how do I access the actual URL stored, or represented by ":back"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] in your controller, but be aware, that this can always be nil

Answer (score 2):

Rails uses `request.headers["Referer"]` and raises an error if it's nil.

Source:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L87